# linq join with groupby and max issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm playing around with Entity Framework and having a lot of trouble replicating the linq query that is relatively straightforward in SQL.

```
public class ReportQueueServiceCommandDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommandDatetime { get; set; }
    public int CommandId { get; set; }
    public bool IsCommandAcknowledged { get; set; }
    public int QueueNumber { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<ReportQueueServiceCommandDTO> GetLastestUnprocessedRequestsPerQueue()
{

    // Get the maximum Acknowledged record per queue
    var maxDateTimesPerAcknowledgedQueue = this.Get()
        .Where(w => w.IsCommandAcknowledged)
        .GroupBy(gb => gb.QueueNumber)
        .Select(s => new ReportQueueServiceCommandDTO()
        {
            Id = (int)s.Max(m => m.Id),
            CommandDatetime = s.FirstOrDefault(fod => fod.Id == s.Max(max => max.Id)).CommandDatetime, 
            CommandId = s.FirstOrDefault(fod => fod.Id == s.Max(max => max.Id)).CommandId,
            IsCommandAcknowledged = true,
            QueueNumber = s.Key
        });

    // Get the maximum unacknowledged record which had an ID greater than the maximum acknowledged record per queue.
    // If the queue entry does not yet exist from MaxDateTimesPerAcknowledgedQueue, use the record anyway (left join-ish)
    return from record in _context.ReportQueueServiceCommands
           from maxRecord in MaxDateTimesPerAcknowledgedQueue.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where record.QueueNumber == (maxRecord == null ? record.QueueNumber : maxRecord.QueueNumber)
             && record.Id > (maxRecord == null ? 0 : maxRecord.Id)
             && !record.IsCommandAcknowledged
           group record by record.QueueNumber into groupedRecords
           select new ReportQueueServiceCommandDTO()
           {
               Id = (int)groupedRecords.Max(m => m.Id),
               CommandDatetime = groupedRecords.FirstOrDefault(fod => fod.Id == groupedRecords.Max(max => max.Id)).CommandDatetime,
               CommandId = groupedRecords.FirstOrDefault(fod => fod.Id == groupedRecords.Max(max => max.Id)).CommandId,
               IsCommandAcknowledged = false,
               QueueNumber = groupedRecords.Key
           };

}
```

Using the above code i get an exception

> The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive,
>   enumeration, or reference type

when attempting to iterate through the results of `GetLatestUnprocessedRequestsPerQueue()`

If I change my query to:

```
return from record in _context.ReportQueueServiceCommands
       from maxRecord in MaxDateTimesPerAcknowledgedQueue
       where record.QueueNumber == maxRecord.QueueNumber
         && record.Id > maxRecord.Id
         && !record.IsCommandAcknowledged
       group record by record.QueueNumber into groupedRecords
       select new ReportQueueServiceCommandDTO()
       {
           Id = (int)groupedRecords.Max(m => m.Id),
           CommandDatetime = groupedRecords.FirstOrDefault(fod => fod.Id == groupedRecords.Max(max => max.Id)).CommandDatetime,
           CommandId = groupedRecords.FirstOrDefault(fod => fod.Id == groupedRecords.Max(max => max.Id)).CommandId,
           IsCommandAcknowledged = false,
           QueueNumber = groupedRecords.Key
       };
```

I don't get my error, and I *almost* get the results I want, however if that queue has happened to not have a successfully processed command, then there will be no record for that queue in `maxDateTimesPerAcknowledgedQueue`.

EDIT: Given data:

```
    Id    CommandDatetime    CommandId    IsCommandAcknowledged    QueueNumber
    0    2014-01-01          1            0                        1 -- should be returned as it is the maximum unacknowledged record for this queue when there are *no* acknowledged records for the queue.
    1    2013-12-31          1            0                        2 -- should not be returned as it is not the maximum unacknowledged record greater than the maximum acknowledged record
    2    2014-01-01          1            1                        2 -- should not be returned as already acknowledged
    3    2014-01-01          1            0                        2 -- should not be returned as it is not the maximum unacknowledged record greater than the maximum acknowledged record
    4    2014-01-02          1            0                        2 -- should be returned as it is the maximum unackowledged record past its maximum acknowledged record
    5    2014-01-01          1            1                        3 -- should not be returned as there are no "unacknowledged" records for this queue
```

Expected Result:

```
    Id    CommandDatetime    CommandId    IsCommandAcknowledged    QueueNumber
    0    2014-01-01          1            0                        1
    4    2014-01-01          1            0                        2
```

Actual Result:

```
    Id    CommandDatetime    CommandId    IsCommandAcknowledged    QueueNumber
    4    2014-01-01          1            0                        2
```

The issue with the "Actual result" is there have not been any acknowledged records for Queue 1, so that record is not being returned (but i need it to be).  Might be reiterating here, but what I'm trying to accomplish is:

> Return the maximum unacknowledged record per queue, greater than the
>   maximum acknowledged record per queue, if no acknowledged record
>   exists for a queue, return the maxumum unacknowledged record.

I hope it makes sense what I'm trying to accomplish, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to accomplish what I wanted, though it feels extremely clunky and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get the latest unprocessed batch service command per queue
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public IQueryable<ReportQueueServiceCommandDTO> GetLatestUnprocessedCommandFromQueue()
{

    // Get the maximum Acknowledged record per queue
    var maxDateTimePerAcknowledgedQueue = this.Get()
        .Where(w => w.IsCommandAcknowledged)
        .GroupBy(gb => gb.QueueNumber)
        .Select(s => new ReportQueueServiceCommandDTO()
        {
            Id = (int)s.Max(m => m.Id),
            CommandDatetime = s.FirstOrDefault(fod => fod.Id == s.Max(max => max.Id)).CommandDatetime,
            CommandId = s.FirstOrDefault(fod => fod.Id == s.Max(max => max.Id)).CommandId,
            IsCommandAcknowledged = true,
            QueueNumber = s.Key
        });

    // Get the maximum unacknowledged record per queue
    var maxDateTimePerUnacknowledgedQueue = this.Get()
        .Where(w => !w.IsCommandAcknowledged)
        .GroupBy(gb => gb.QueueNumber)
        .Select(s => new ReportQueueServiceCommandDTO()
        {
            Id = (int)s.Max(m => m.Id),
            CommandDatetime = s.FirstOrDefault(fod => fod.Id == s.Max(max => max.Id)).CommandDatetime,
            CommandId = s.FirstOrDefault(fod => fod.Id == s.Max(max => max.Id)).CommandId,
            IsCommandAcknowledged = false,
            QueueNumber = s.Key
        });

    // Get the maximum unacknowledged record which had an ID greater than the maximum acknowledged record per queue.
    // If the queue entry does not yet exist from MaxDateTimesPerAcknowledgedQueue, use the record anyway (left join-ish)
    return (from unack in maxDateTimePerUnacknowledgedQueue
           join ack in maxDateTimePerAcknowledgedQueue on unack.QueueNumber equals ack.QueueNumber into joinedRecords
           from subAck in joinedRecords.Where(w => w.Id > unack.Id).DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new ReportQueueServiceCommandDTO()
           {
               Id = (subAck.Id == null ? unack.Id : subAck.Id),
               CommandDatetime = (subAck.CommandDatetime == null ? unack.CommandDatetime : subAck.CommandDatetime),
               CommandId = (subAck.CommandId == null ? unack.CommandId : subAck.CommandId),
               IsCommandAcknowledged = (subAck.IsCommandAcknowledged == null ? unack.IsCommandAcknowledged : subAck.IsCommandAcknowledged),
               QueueNumber = (subAck.QueueNumber == null ? unack.QueueNumber : subAck.QueueNumber)
           })
           .Where(w => !w.IsCommandAcknowledged);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for null: `maxRecord == null` is the problem.

use `ToList()` before checking for null.

[Entity Framework: The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive or reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12773206/entity-framework-the-argument-to-dbisnullexpression-must-refer-to-a-primitive-o)

Comment: where are you suggesting this be done in the code from my question? I have tried in a combination of several areas but have not had luck.  I'm unclear on why this would fix my issue, so I'm having trouble figuring out where this would need to be done.

Comment: `_context.ReportQueueServiceCommands.ToList()` and
`MaxDateTimesPerAcknowledgedQueue.DefaultIfEmpty().ToList()`

Comment: That gets rid of my runtime error, but I only arrive at the same result set that was posted in the "If I change my query to:" section of the question, it does not actually arrive at the result that was the real basis of my question. :(

Comment: I don't get this sentence: `if that queue has happened to not have a successfully processed command, then there will be no record for that queue in maxDateTimesPerAcknowledgedQueue`. Please explain the situation when you don't get the results you want.

Comment: Sorry about that, added some sample data w/ expected results in the question - hopefully that helps make it clearer what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Can you please write the actual results other than expected results?

Comment: in your example values, could it be because of `0` in:
`record.Id > (maxRecord == null ? 0 : maxRecord.Id)`? because record.id is 0 and is not greater than 0