# Left Outer Join in Entity Framework (Linq). Member materializing to Null

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, left-join

**Problem:**

Could I perform the left join and verify the `null`ed element without 
terminating the DB link? If yes, how do I do it?

**Trial Code**

```
var transactions1 = (from tran in ctx.transactions
    group tran.Amount by new { tran.UserID, tran.LeaveID } into leave
    select new { UserID = leave.Key.UserID, LeaveID = leave.Key.LeaveID, Balance = leave.Sum() });

var transactions2 = (from tran in ctx.transactions
    where tran.Type == type && tran.FiscalYear == fiscal
    group tran.Amount by new { tran.UserID, tran.LeaveID } into leave
    select new { UserID = leave.Key.UserID, LeaveID = leave.Key.LeaveID, Rollout = leave.Sum() });

var computed = (from balance in transactions1
               join join_rollout in transactions2 on new { balance.UserID, balance.LeaveID } equals new { join_rollout.UserID, join_rollout.LeaveID } into rolls
               from rollout in rolls.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select new
               {
                   UserID = balance.UserID,
                   LeaveID = balance.LeaveID,
                   computed = rollout.Rollout
               }).ToList();
```

**Goal**:

I am trying to left join two tables using linq. As one could guess, some values of the second table could result in `null`. If I use a ternary operator to verify `null`ed values the application throws the following exception

> The argument to **DbIsNullExpression** must refer to a primitive, enumeration or reference type.

Find the stack trace at [PastBin](http://pastebin.com/KwUrnWN1)

If I remove the ternary verification, the application throws the following exception

> The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Find the stack trace at [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/40kq4r9n)

**Working solution**:

I am able to avoid these exceptions by terminating the DB link (using `.ToList()` as suggested by [slawek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21188777/1799502)) before the final join (that is, `transactions1.ToList() and transactions2.ToList()`. However I wish to avoid using `.ToList()` because I need to perform another join with a DB table which cannot be done on a List.

**My Experiments Since the SO post**

- I've tried using `UseDatabaseNullSemantics` which I did not expect to resolve it but atleast aid in a workaround, but the result is **`Failed`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message that you quoted:

> The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the
>   materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter
>   or the query must use a nullable type.

indicates that you are attempting to assing the value of `null` to a field of `System.Decimal` type. This is illegal in .Net. `System.Decimal` is a value type. Unlike a reference type these cannot be `null`. A good treatment on reference type vs value type can be found [here](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).

When .NET first came out that basically was it. Later on, it became obvious that this can be very inconvenient, so .net designers tucked on a new feature called [nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx). These allow getting around this limitation above. In c# you refer to a nullable type, by specifying a value type and then adding a question mark to it, like this: `System.Decimal?` or simply `decimal?`. A field of `decimal?` type will be able to hold `null`.

You need to tell the compiler the type you are using, it can't figure it out correctly on its own. Change this line of your code:

```
computed = rollout.Rollout
```

to read like this:

```
computed = (decimal?)rollout.Rollout
```

This will indicated that null is a valid value, and your code will work.

In general, it helps taking some time to learning the basics, *before* diving into more complicated stuff like ORM usage. If you do not know the basics, when something breaks it's very difficult to identify *what* broke - since you don't have all the pieces of the puzzle, but once you know them, often the answer is obvious.

Comment: that is a very simple but efficient solution, I should say that I am aware of nullable types and as you see in my question I tried avoiding null values by testing the `rollout` object. I would assume from your answer that null values cannot be evaluated using the ternary `?:` operator (when the DB link is active). But thank you this is a very simple workaround.